# What does methyl bromide look like on timber?

Tags: safety, outdoor, pallet

I have timber from pallets without any stamps. From my research, un-stamped pallets may be for domestic use and, therefore, are not treated in any way.

With that said the timber has some granular whiteness in places. It is almost like salt in texture with occasional granules on the surface. There is no odour.

The image shows the whiteness on the right mostly. Is this methyl bromide?

Ultimately my question is one of safety. Should I use this timber for outdoor furniture and dog houses?

[image]

Comment: Are you in Europe and if so where?

Comment: Not Europe, Australia.

Comment: Ah. I don't know what the standards are for Oz or the Pacific rim, I started out using a lot of pallet wood (both domestic pieces and the occasional import using hardwoods) and none had any markings. And like lots of other people I had no apparent ill effects from handling or working with it, **but**, the positive experiences of other people should not be taken as a clear sign to go ahead. Although I wouldn't put it as prescriptively as in the Answer you've received you never know for sure with pallet wood, and the toss of the coin is always up to the individual.

Answer (score 1):

Second-hand pallet timber should not be used for anything except pallets or industrial use.

The problem is two-fold: you don't know how the pallet was originally treated, nor what the pallet experienced during use. It could have been dragged through toxic chemicals or had contaminated contents placed on it for transport.

If safety is really your concern don't use pallets for anything with close proximity to humans, animals, or your food supply.